# Cannot re-pair bluetooth keyboard after removing device once

Tags: wireless, 22.04, bluetooth, connection, wireless-keyboards

*(Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS x86_64 / GNOME 42.9 / 6.2.0-1011-lowlatency kernel)*

I have a Thinkpad Trackpoint II wireless keyboard with Bluetooth support. Occasionally there will be problems when waking up the computer from sleep, so I tried removing the device from the `gnome-control-center` Bluetooth page to troubleshoot.

Now, I cannot get the keyboard to re-pair at all. When attempting to connect, I will be prompted to enter a PIN, and upon entering it nothing will happen. No indication as to what's going wrong, just that same window with the PIN number. Sometimes, it changes PINs, but that's all it does:

[image]

I have tried pairing through the default `gnome-control-center`, `blueman-manager` and `bluetoothctl`, all with and without `sudo`. The only time I gained some success was through using `bluetoothctl`, but after about a minute it would just disconnect my keyboard again. Sometimes, I will get only trackpoint and mouse button functionality, but that would soon be disconnected as well.

I've tried checking [Lenovo's user manual](https://download.lenovo.com/consumer/options/trackpoint_keyboard_II_user_guide_en.pdf) for an option to factory reset the keyboard, in case it was something related to it's firmware, but I cannot find any way to do that. I have spent a considerable amount of time on this and I am completely out of ideas, would really appreciate some help here.

**Note: The Bluetooth worked before, so there is no reason why it shouldn't be working now. The only problem was when I would wake up my computer from sleep with my USB mouse, or something other than the Bluetooth-connected Keyboard. When this happens the keyboard's Bluetooth would not work until restarting the computer. This is why I went and removed the device from Bluetooth settings in the first place, I was trying to troubleshoot without having to restart the computer.**

**Also of note: I have a Microsoft Xbox controller connected via Bluetooth, and it still works fine.**

Thank you